# @.SYNTAX-ERROR. in PHP mail sender

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, phpmailer

I am using a HTML form to forward inputs via ajax to a PHP file, where an e-mail is sent using PHPMailer. I use JQuery to validate some inputs (name and mail address) before the data is sent to the PHP file.

Here is my code:

HTML Form:

```
<form class="ajax" action="script/send_form.php" method="post">
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text"  />
        <input id="mail" name="mail" type="text"  />
        <input id="mail" name="note" type="text"  />
        <button type="submit" id="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

The PHP file using the Autoload function of PHPMailer:

```
    <?

$return = chr(13).chr(10);
$line = "-----------------------------------------------".$return;

$name = '';
$email = '';

if(!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}

$email = $_POST['mail'];
$note = $_POST['note'];

$msg = $note;

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;


//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('info@internet.com', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Some Subject';


$mail->Body = $msg;

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mail Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Sent";
}

?>
```

Jquery:

```
   function validateEmail(email) { 

    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function validate(){
    var email = $("#mail").val();
      if (validateEmail(email)) {
          var mail = $('#mail').val();
      } else {
  alert ('Bitte gültite E-Mail Adresse eingeben!') 
      }
}

function dottedButton () {
  document.getElementById('send').innerHTML = '...';
} 


$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
     validate ();

     var name = $('#name').val();
     var mail = $('#mail').val();

     if(name && mail){

            var that = $(this);
                url = that.attr('action');
                type = that.attr('method');
                contents = that.serialize();
        dottedButton ();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: type,
                data: contents,
                success: function(response){
                    document.getElementById('send').innerHTML = 'sent';
                }
            });
     } else {
        alert ('pleas fill out all fields!') 
     };
    return false;
});
```

The problem is: in unregular intervals (every one or two days) i have an e-mail in my inbox, that is empty and the sender e-mail address says: @.SYNTAX-ERROR.

I have no clue, why this is happening. Might it be possible that some bot autosends the PHPMailer?

BTW: My hoster is hoststar.at

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

```
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;
```

You're trying to forge the sender address and you will have delivery trouble, and you're open to problems like you're seeing. Just put the submitted from address in the message body, or reply-to if you need it in headers.